# Moving objects in Jframe

Tags: java, swing, listener, mouselistener

I've got some kind of JButton I want to move, for example in this code:

```
package javaapplication19;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;


public class JavaApplication19 extends JFrame{
    public static JButton button=new JButton("Button");//Button to move
    public static int x;
    public static int y;
    public JavaApplication19(){
        final Container C = getContentPane();
        C.setLayout(null);
        button.setBounds(100,100,100,100);
        C.add(button);
        //MouseListenerStart
    button.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    if(!e.isMetaDown()){
    x = e.getX();
    y = e.getY();
    }
    }
    });
    button.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
    if(!e.isMetaDown()){
    Point p = getLocation();
    button.setLocation(p.x + e.getX() - x,
    p.y + e.getY() - y);
    }
    }
    });
//MouseListenerend
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JavaApplication19 marco=new JavaApplication19 ();
        marco.setSize(1000,700);
        marco.setVisible(true);
        marco.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);    
    }}
```

But there are 2 problems. The first one is that the JButton moves slower than the mouse. The second one is that the JButton seems to jump between two places in the JFrame when dragging it.

How could I solve these problems?

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

In this code:

```
package javaapplication19;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;


public class JavaApplication19 extends JFrame{
    public static JButton button=new JButton("Button");//Button to move
    public static int x;
    public static int y;
    public JavaApplication19(){
        final Container C = getContentPane();
        C.setLayout(null);
        button.setBounds(100,100,100,100);
        C.add(button);
        //MouseListenerStart
    button.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    if(!e.isMetaDown()){
    x = e.getX();
    y = e.getY();
    }
    }
    });
    button.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
    if(!e.isMetaDown()){
    Point p = button.getLocation();\\I Simply had to put button.getLocation() instead of getLocation()
    button.setLocation(p.x + e.getX() - x,
    p.y + e.getY() - y);
    }
    }
    });
//MouseListenerend
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JavaApplication19 marco=new JavaApplication19 ();
        marco.setSize(1000,700);
        marco.setVisible(true);
        marco.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);    
    }
}
```

Comment: You are using static variables incorrectly. There is no need for static variables in your example. If you think you need them then you have a design problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to write more generic code that can be used for any component. The code you posted in your solution is hard coded so that it will only ever work for a variable called "button".

For a more generic solution that will allow you to drag any component check out the `Basic Dragging` section found in [Moving Windows](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/06/14/moving-windows/).